# How to make a random input appear in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, random

I'm developing a website, and wanted to make a few input fields, and if you press the button one of the inputs will show up (`.innerHTML`). Here's the HTML, but I don't know the jQuery and searched the internet, but couldn't find anyrhing usefull...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter a word">

<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter a word">
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter a word">
<input type="button" value="Go!">
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Well, *first* you'd add a click handler then when when it was triggered you'd generate a 'random value' and assign it to the value attribute (not innerHTML) of the particular input field.. it would probably be a good time to go through some basic tutorials (that walk through the entire process of creating something simple, like a calculator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>      
  <form>
  <hr/>
    <a href="javascript:;void(0);" id="buttonOne">Insert input form</a>
  <hr/>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Post the form" /> 
    
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var sequence = 0;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        $("#buttonOne").click(function(){
            $("form").prepend("<input name=name"+sequence+" placeholder='something' type='text' /> <br/> ");
            sequence++;
        });

        $("form").submit(function(e){
            
            $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
               if($(this).val() == "") $(this).remove();
            });

            if( $('input[type=text]').size() >= 2  ){
               
              random_number = parseInt( Math.random() * $('input[type=text]').size() );

                alert(  $('input[type=text]:eq('+random_number+')').val()  );

             }else{
              alert("sorry you need at least 2 fields");

             }
              return false;
        });
      
    });
    
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was one thing I wanted to make, but now I want if you hit the button Submit form, it shows one of all the inputs in innerHTML. (It must only work if 2 or more input fields are filled)

Comment: Thanks again, but it had to say one of the inputs, not how mant inputs there were. Let's say I have 2 fields and type Hello in the first one and LOL and the Second... It has to say Hello or LOL. One of the inputs. It has to be random...